# Spring Integration Webservice vs. RestTemplate

Tags: spring

I'm trying to learn SI (Spring Integration) but i'm a bit confused on the real usage of this.

As first example i would like to interact with a WebService but i dont understand what could be the difference from

- Invoke a WebService Using SI
- Invoke a Webservice using RestTemplate

So, what is the benefit of using SI (in Webservice context, or in other context)?

Looking the web, i havent find an article that explain:

- Usually you will do in this way....
- With SI you can do better - in this another way - and the benefit are....

To be more explicit on what i have to realize, this is an example:

1) I have to write an application (Standalone application) that have to collect some data in the system periodically and then invoke a Web Service that will store it.

2) The Web Service receive the call from the "clients" and store in the database.

**My webservice will use REST.**

The reason because i've think to use SI is that the Standalone Application should interact with different system

- Webservice in first instance
- A Web Mail, if the webservice is not achievable
- File system if Web mail is not achievable too

Comment: To answer this we need to know what you do with the data. If you only get the data once and print it to the screen then SI is overkill

Comment: It's about understanding the difference between SOAP and REST.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to pull some data in a simple way and push it onwards to a REST service this does not "justify" the use of Spring Integration. A simple Spring (Boot) application combined with a scheduler will be sufficient.

But if you want to use a more complex data source for which an [endpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#endpoint-summary) is available, you need transformations, complex and flexible routing is a high priority or even [Enterprise Integration Patterns (EIP)](http://www.eaipatterns.com/) then Spring Integration is for you. Have a look at the [Overview](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#overview-background) and decide if it mentions something you consider as valuable to you.
Perhaps you will create additional value by mixing in Spring Batch if you need to process a lot of data.

But as I understand your current demand starting with just a RESTTemplate should do for the moment. Starting small will not prevent you from switching to Spring Integration later on.
Have a look at the various [tutorials](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) and [guides](http://spring.io/guides) provided by the Spring Boot project. There is even an [example for Spring Integration](http://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/).

Comment: Thanks a lot of your reply. In the past i've already wrote webservice (in a REST way) using  Spring and i was looking forward and trying to write a better flow, more maintainable and expandable, for this reason i've "found" Spring Batch and Spring Integration. Right now, i already know how to invoke a  Webservice or how to write it. My problem was "write  the application better"

Comment: I've forgot an behavior of it... the program that collect data and then invoke the WebSevice could have different behavior, for example if the WebService is not active, the batch program will try to send it via mail and if this fails too... write file on disk for a future execution. I update the    original post.